# How to Alter returned data format called from csv using python

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary, arcgis, arcpy

I am looking for guidance regarding a return result FORMAT from a csv file. The code I have to date partially ahcieves my objective but despite significant effort researching through this and many other sites/forums I cannot resolve the final step. I have also posed this question on gis.stackexchange but was redirected to this forum with the comment *"Questions relating to general Information Technology, with no clear GIS component, are off-topic here, but can be researched/asked at Stack Overflow"*.

My successful piece of python code that reads selected data from a csv and returns it in dict format is below ; (Yes I know the reason it returns as type dict is due to the format my code is calling!!! and that is the crux of the problem)

```
import arcpy, csv
Att_Dict ={}
with open ("C:/Data/Code/Python/Library/Peter/123.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Status']=='Keep':
            Att_Dict.update({row['book_id']:row['book_ref']})  
print Att_Dict 

Att_Dict = {'7643': '7625', '9644': '2289', '4406': '4443', '7588': '9681', '2252': '7947'}
```

For the next part of my code to run I need the result above but in the format of ; (this is part of a very lengthy code but the only show stopper is the returned format so little value in posting the other 200 or so lines)

```
Att_Dict = [[7643, 7625], [9644, 2289], [4406, 4443], [7588, 9681], [2252, 7947]]
```

Although I have experimented endlessly and can achieve this by reverting to csv.Reader rather than csv.DictReader, I then lose the ability to 'weed out' rows where column 'Status' has value 'Keep' in them and that is a requirement for the task at hand.

My sledgehammer approach to date has been to use 'search and replace' within Idle to amend the returned set to the meet the other requirement but Im sure it can be done programatically rather than manually. Similar but not exact to https://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html, plus my startout question at [Returning values from multiple CSV columns to Python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404722/returning-values-from-multiple-csv-columns-to-python-dictionary) and [Using Python's csv.dictreader to search for specific key to then print its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641461/using-pythons-csv-dictreader-to-search-for-specific-key-to-then-print-its-value) plus a multitude of csv based questions at geonet.esri.

(Using Win 7, ArcGIS 10.2, Python 2.7.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Att_Dict = {'7643': '7625', '9644': '2289', '4406': '4443', '7588': '9681', '2252': '7947'}
Att_List = []
for key, value in Att_Dict.items():   
    Att_List.append([int(key), int(value)])

print Att_List

Out: [[7643, 7625], [9644, 2289], [4406, 4443], [7588, 9681], [2252, 7947]]
```

Comment: The question specified Python 2.7.5, so I think iteritems() should be used to iterate through the dictionary.

Comment: Perfect thanks @seenu-s. That gives the result I have been looking for.